# Ruby system() doesn't accept UTF-8?

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 in Windows and trying to perform an action where I write filenames to a file one per line (we'll call it a filelist) and then later read this filelist, and call system() to run another program where I will pass it a filename from the filelist.  That program I'm calling with system() will take the filename I pass it and convert it to a binary format to be used in a proprietary system.

Everything works up to the point of calling system().  I have a UTF-8 filelist, and reading the filename from the filelist is giving me the proper result.  But when I run

```
system("c:\foo.exe -arg #{bar}")
```

the arg "bar" being passed is not in UTF-8 format.  If I run the program manually with a Japanese, chinese, or whatever filename it works fine and codes the file correctly, but if I do it using system() it won't.  I know the variable in bar is stored properly because I use it elsewhere without issue.

I've also tried:

```
system("c:\foo.exe -arg #{bar.encoding("UTF-8")}")
system("c:\foo.exe -arg #{bar.force_encoding("UTF-8")}")
```

and neither work.  I can only assume the issue here is passing unicode to system.

Can someone else confirm if system does, in fact, support or not support this?

Here is the block of code:

```
  $fname.each do |file|
    flist.write("#{file}\n")  # This is written properly in UTF-8
    system("ia.exe -r \"#{file}\" -q xbfadd") # The file being passed here is not encoding right!
  end
```

Comment: This appears to be a long-standing problem with abysmal integration into Windows on Ruby's side. Apparently until recently it still used the ANSI APIs for plenty of things and `system` might have been overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby's `system()` function, like that in most scripting languages, is a veneer over the C standard library `system()` call. The MS C runtime uses Win32 ANSI APIs for all the byte-oriented C stdlib functions.

The ANSI APIs use the Windows system locale (aka 'ANSI codepage') to map between byte-oriented  strings and Windows's native-UTF16LE strings which are used for filenames and shell commands. Unfortunately, it is impossible to set the system locale to UTF-8; you can set the codepage to 65001 (Windows's equivalent to UTF-8) on a particular console, but the MS CRT has long-standing bugs in its handling of code page 65001 which make a lot of applications fail.

So using the standard cross-platform byte-oriented C interfaces means you can't support Unicode filenames or shell commands, which is rather sad. Some scripting languages have added support for Unicode filenames by calling the Win32 'W' (Unicode) APIs explicitly instead of the C stdlib interfaces. Ruby 1.9.x is making progress in this area, but `system()` has not been looked at yet.

You can fix it by [calling the Win32 API yourself](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/dl/rdoc/Win32API.html), for example [CreateProcessW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it's not especially pretty.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted bobince's answer; I believe it correct.

The only thing I'd add is that an additional work-around, this being a windows problem, is to write out the commandline to a batch file and then use system() to call the batchfile.

I used this approach to successfully get around the problem while running Calibre's ebook-convert commandline tool for a book with UTF-8/non-English chars in its title.

Answer (score 0):

I think that bobince answer is correct and the solution that worked for me was:

```
system("c:\foo.exe -arg #{bar.encoding("ISO-8859-1")}")
```